# XGBoost: label set cannot be empty when using a copy of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, xgboost

I am currently trying to train my XGBoost model for specific data of my original dataframe "data" with the following code. The problem is when I am using the original dataframe as left part of my join as follows, everything works fine with my model.

```
join = pd.merge(data, data_shift, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=('', '_lag'))
```

But when I use the dataframe "location_product_data" as left part of my merge/join, than the fitting raises the error message mentioned above.

```
data = data_raw.copy()
data = data.drop(['Number of day', 'Number of working days'], axis=1)


uniqueLocations = data['SC'].unique().tolist()
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'])
data = data.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['DATE']))   

year = '2015'

for location in uniqueLocations:
    location_data = data.loc[data['SC'] == sc].copy()
    uniqueProducts = location_data['SPK'].unique().tolist()

    for product in uniqueProducts:
        location_product_data = location_data.loc[location_data['SPK'] == product].copy()
        #split complete dataset in training and test data
        split_date = year+'-10-01'

        data_shift = location_product_data.shift(1).copy()
        data_shift = data_shift.drop(['SC', 'SPK'], axis=1).copy()

        join = pd.merge(location_product_data, data_shift, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=('', '_lag'))

        join['NS AC_lag'] = join['NS AC'] - join['NS AC_lag']

        data_train = join.loc[join.index <= split_date].copy()
        data_test = join.loc[join.index > split_date].copy()

        X_train, y_train = create_features(data_train, label='NS AC')
        X_test, y_test = create_features(data_test, label='NS AC')

        reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000)

        params = {
            'base_score': np.mean(y_train),
            'eta':  0.1,
            'max_depth': 3,
            'gamma' :3,
            'objective'   :'reg:squarederror',
            'eval_metric' :'mae'
            }

        reg.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
                early_stopping_rounds=50,
                verbose=True)
```

.

```
def create_features(df, label=None):
    """
    Creates time series features from datetime index
    """
    df['DATE'] = df.index
    df['quarter'] = df['DATE'].dt.quarter
    df['month'] = df['DATE'].dt.month
    df['year'] = df['DATE'].dt.year
    df['lag'] = df['NS AC_lag']
    #df['lag2'] = df['NS AC_lag2']
    #df['lag3'] = df['NS AC_lag3']
    #df['min'] = df['min']
    #df['mean'] = df['mean']
    #df['max'] = df['max']
    #df['t+1'] = df['t+1']
    #df['spk'] = df['SPK']

    #X = df[['month','quarter','year', 'lag', 'lag2','lag3','min', 'mean', 'max', 't+1']]
    X = df[['month','quarter','year', 'lag']]
    #X = df[['month','quarter','year', 'Number of day', 'Number of working days','lag', 'lag2','lag3','min', 'mean', 'max', 't+1']]
    if label:
        y = df[label]
        return X, y
    return X
```

Do you have any idea why the error is raised? I couldn't find a reason yet why it doesn't.
Thanks! :)

Error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-9232809a4751> in <module>
     83                     eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
     84                     early_stopping_rounds=50,
---> 85                     verbose=False)
     86 
     87             #print('Training finished.')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, callbacks)
    394                               evals_result=evals_result, obj=obj, feval=feval,
    395                               verbose_eval=verbose, xgb_model=xgb_model,
--> 396                               callbacks=callbacks)
    397 
    398         if evals_result:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.py in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, xgb_model, callbacks, learning_rates)
    214                            evals=evals,
    215                            obj=obj, feval=feval,
--> 216                            xgb_model=xgb_model, callbacks=callbacks)
    217 
    218 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.py in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks)
     82         # check evaluation result.
     83         if evals:
---> 84             bst_eval_set = bst.eval_set(evals, i, feval)
     85             if isinstance(bst_eval_set, STRING_TYPES):
     86                 msg = bst_eval_set

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in eval_set(self, evals, iteration, feval)
   1170                                               dmats, evnames,
   1171                                               c_bst_ulong(len(evals)),
-> 1172                                               ctypes.byref(msg)))
   1173         res = msg.value.decode()
   1174         if feval is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in _check_call(ret)
    174     """
    175     if ret != 0:
--> 176         raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
    177 
    178 

XGBoostError: [15:41:05] /workspace/src/metric/elementwise_metric.cu:325: Check failed: info.labels_.Size() != 0U (0 vs. 0) : label set cannot be empty
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /opt/conda/xgboost/libxgboost.so(dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()+0x24) [0x7fae2412ecb4]
  [bt] (1) /opt/conda/xgboost/libxgboost.so(xgboost::metric::EvalEWiseBase<xgboost::metric::EvalRowRMSE>::Eval(xgboost::HostDeviceVector<float> const&, xgboost::MetaInfo const&, bool)+0xfe) [0x7fae243102ee]
  [bt] (2) /opt/conda/xgboost/libxgboost.so(xgboost::LearnerImpl::EvalOneIter(int, std::vector<xgboost::DMatrix*, std::allocator<xgboost::DMatrix*> > const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)+0x3c9) [0x7fae241c8d99]
  [bt] (3) /opt/conda/xgboost/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterEvalOneIter+0x371) [0x7fae2412b651]
  [bt] (4) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7fae8f98eec0]
  [bt] (5) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x22d) [0x7fae8f98e87d]
  [bt] (6) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x2ce) [0x7fae8fba4f7e]
  [bt] (7) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x139b4) [0x7fae8fba59b4]
  [bt] (8) /opt/conda/bin/python(_PyObject_FastCallKeywords+0x49b) [0x557ed8936d2b]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The following lines may return an empty Dataframe. I fixed this and the fitting/training works now.

```
    data_train = join.loc[join.index <= split_date].copy()
    data_test = join.loc[join.index > split_date].copy()
```